# Exception #0 (UnexpectedValueException): Setup version for module 'MagePal_GmailSmtpApp' is not specified

Tags: magento2, error, email, configuration

the website was working fine until i changed an email setting from the admin panel, all of a sudden the website only shows this error

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (UnexpectedValueException): Setup version for module 'MagePal_GmailSmtpApp' is not specified

Exception #0 (UnexpectedValueException): Setup version for module 'MagePal_GmailSmtpApp' is not specified
#0 /h/s/ph/vendor/magento/framework/Module/DbVersionInfo.php(56): Magento\Framework\Module\DbVersionInfo->isModuleVersionEqual('MagePal_GmailSm...', '1.4.1')
#1 /h/s/ph/vendor/magento/framework/Module/DbVersionInfo.php(79): Magento\Framework\Module\DbVersionInfo->isSchemaUpToDate('MagePal_GmailSm...')
#2 /h/s/ph/vendor/magento/framework/Module/Plugin/DbStatusValidator.php(55): Magento\Framework\Module\DbVersionInfo->getDbVersionErrors()
#3 /h/s/ph/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#4 /h/s/ph/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#5 /h/s/ph/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#6 /h/s/ph/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#7 /h/s/ph/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#8 {main}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
php -f bin/magento module:enable --clear-static-content MagePal_GmailSmtpApp
php -f bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

**hope its work for you**